# How to use JavaScript to show embedded youtube videos on click

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I am trying to create a page in which I want to embed 5-10 youtube videos. Only 1 video will appear on the right side of the page and video titles will remain on the left side. Click on title makes respective video appear on right div. I have tried it, but not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Youtube Videos Page

```
<style type="text/css">

    body{
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #leftdiv{
        background-color: #A9F5D0;
        float: left;
        height:100%;
        width: 30%;

    }

    #rightdiv{
        background-color: #F8E0F1;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 70%;
    }

    #lectname{
        padding:10px;
        font-family: "comic sans ms";
    }


</style>
```

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="leftdiv">

        <div id="lectname">
            <p id="lectname1">Lec 01: What is Signal?</p>
            <p id="lectname2">Lec 02: What is an Analog Signal?</p>
            <p id="lectname3">Lec 03: What is Digital Signal?</p>
            <p id="lectname4">Lec 04: Need of Digital Signal</p>
            <p id="lectname5">Lec 05: Introduction to Digital Electronics</p>
            <p id="lectname6">Lec 06: Switch and Bits Intuition</p>
        </div>          

    </div>

    <div id="rightdiv">
        <iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0mx8S05v60" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>  

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("lectname1").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0mx8S05v60" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

    document.getElementById("lectname2").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F5h3z8p9dPg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

    document.getElementById("lectname3").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jRL9ag3riJY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

    document.getElementById("lectname4").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/izBaDRyqnBk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

    document.getElementById("lectname5").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2xXErGeeb_Q" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

    document.getElementById("lectname6").onclick=function(){
        document.getElementById("rightdiv").innerHTML='<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RF9I6UzI4Rc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }

</script>
```

Comment: So what's the problem, seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/r6uf8r5h/

Comment: One crazzzzy idea man,, why not use native youtube playlist embed and ditch all js, css stuff :) http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/ygxbuy7y/ looks nice and cool

Comment: Why is it crazzy? Is there any drawbacks? I cannot just embed whole playlist because I want to divide lectures based on chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works fine.  I would suggest changing the source of the iFrame instead of replacing the html inside the div.  I've also changed the script to make it a little easier to read instead of having all those manual on click calls.

```css
    body{
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #leftdiv{
        background-color: #A9F5D0;
        float: left;
        height:100%;
        width: 30%;

    }

    #rightdiv{
        background-color: #F8E0F1;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 70%;
    }

    #lectname{
        padding:10px;
        font-family: "comic sans ms";
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="leftdiv">

        <div id="lectname">
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname1">Lec 01: What is Signal?</p>
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname2">Lec 02: What is an Analog Signal?</p>
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname3">Lec 03: What is Digital Signal?</p>
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname4">Lec 04: Need of Digital Signal</p>
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname5">Lec 05: Introduction to Digital Electronics</p>
            <p class="videoLink" id="lectname6">Lec 06: Switch and Bits Intuition</p>
        </div>          

    </div>

    <div id="rightdiv">
        <iframe id="videoFrame" width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0mx8S05v60" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>  

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var lectureVideos = {
  lectname1: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/M0mx8S05v60",
  lectname2: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/F5h3z8p9dPg",
  lectname3: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/jRL9ag3riJY",
  lectname4: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/izBaDRyqnBk",
  lectname5: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/2xXErGeeb_Q",
  lectname6: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/RF9I6UzI4Rc"
 }
 
 var videoLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("videoLink");
 for(var i=0; i<videoLinks.length; i++){
  videoLinks[i].onclick=function(){
   document.getElementById("videoFrame").src=lectureVideos[this.id];
  }
 }
 
 

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is much better.